# single qoute syntax printing in php

Tags: php, html

The below outputs

```
href="javascript:showBed(" a114:1')'
```

when I want it on the form

```
href="javascript:showBed('A114:1')"
```

in order to get javascript to work. I had a look at [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) but coudn't get it to work so I gave up. Perhaps you could give me a hint on how the corrent syntax would be?

```
  echo("<a href='javascript:showBed('" . $row['Bed'] ."')' target='main' class='larmlink'>link</a>");
```

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is not what it would output, but it *is* how it would be interpreted (HINT: don't look at a parsed DOM tree, look at the *source*).

```
echo("<a href='javascript:showBed('" . $row['Bed'] ."')' ...
```

==>

```
echo("<a href=\"javascript:showBed('" . $row['Bed'] ."')\" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to output variable data to JavaScript, it is good to use `json_encode()` so that all special characters are escaped automatically.  The `htmlspecialchars()` escapes any values for use in the HTML attribute value.

```
echo '<a href="',
  htmlspecialchars('javascript:showBed(' .  json_encode($row['Bed']) .   ')'),
  '" target="main" class="larmlink">link</a>';
```

Note that I use single quotes for PHP string literals so that PHP doesn't have to search through my string for a variable to replace.  You don't have to do this, but I recommend it.

Comment: This won't work, you still need to quote the arguments and escape the quotes.

Comment: @Greg, Fixed.  Note that you don't have to quote the JavaScript value... just for HTML. `json_encode()` quotes JS strings.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using the more standard double quotes around HTML element properties.  As such, it is probably best to use single quotes in PHP.  I would suggest this:

```
echo('<a href="javascript:showBed(\'' . $row['Bed'] .'\')" target="main" class="larmlink">link</a>');
```

Comment: It's a matter of preference.  I prefer double quotes for HTML attribute values as well, but both are perfectly valid.  Also, your answer will not work for all values of `$row['Bed']`.  See my answer for the correct solution.

Comment: @Brad I certainly like your suggestion on json_encoding, though I think the average person might have trouble understanding how the json_encode behavior differs when just passing a single string value to it.

Answer (score 1):

To print the double-quote character, you can escape it by doing `\"`

```
echo("<a href=\"javascript:showBed('" . $row['bed'] ."')\" target='main' class='larmlink'>link</a>");
```

[Live demo](http://codepad.org/mWLleSfm)

Comment: This will not work for all values of `$row['bed']`. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) often makes code with mixed quotes easier to understand:

```
echo <<<EOD
    <a href="javascript:showBed('$row[Bed]')" target="main" class="larmlink">link</a>
EOD;
```

As others mentioned, if the value of your `$row['Bed']` might contain single or double quotes, you have to escape it with [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes).

Comment: But, this doesn't solve the problem of escaping values of `$row['Bed']`....

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) (or [printf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), but `sprintf` is easier to refactor) for long strings like this so it's easy to see the template:

```
echo sprintf("<a href='javascript:showBed(\"%s\")' target='main' class='larmlink'>link</a>", $row['Bed']);
```

I'd also consider using [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on the `$row['Bed']` variable in case it has quotes in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to avoid to escape anything:

```
echo <<<LOD
<a href="javascript:showBed('{$row['Bed']}')" target="main" class="larmlink">link</a>
LOD;
```

Notice that if your variables contains some quotes you must use the [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function or str_replace before.

Another good practive is to separate systematically all the html content from php code:

```
<a href="javascript:showBed('<?php
echo $row['Bed'];
?>')" target="main" class="larmlink">link</a>
```

Comment: Your heredoc syntax is unnecessarily complex (no need for `{`, `}`, and the `'`s inside) - see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
echo("<a href='javascript:showBed(\"" . $row['Bed'] ."\")' target='main' class='larmlink'>link</a>");
```